# How to implement successive jquery functions- select followed by keypress/keydown

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to simulate keypress by buttons using jquery. But cannot figure out how buttons can trigger a select/click followed by a keypress/keydown event. Can someone please help?

**Requirement: Whenever I press the + or - button, it should slide the dot right or left and it should update the year**

[image]

My code is

```js
$("#range").on("change", function() {
  $("#year").html($(this).val());
});

$("#down-year").on("click", function() {
  $("#range").trigger("select").trigger("keypress", function(e) {
    e.which = 37; //Left arrow
  })
});

$("#up-year").on("click", function() {
  $("#range").trigger("select").trigger("keypress", function(e) {
    e.which = 39; //Right arrow
  })
});
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #28A745;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #28A745;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer text-center">
  <input type="range" min="1966" max="2015" value="2015" class="slider" id="range">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button id="down-year">
                    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <small>Year:&nbsp;<strong id="year" class="text-success">2015</strong></small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button id="up-year">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And how I'm trying with jQuery [Even tried swapping keypress with keydown]:**

Comment: Normally, on clicking the slider dot, it slides freely and also updates the #year element properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have to call the keyup/keydown/keypress events. The way you've got it setup right now you can just increment the range value by 1, up or down. Also it would probably be better to create an "updateLabel()" function instead of triggering another event.

JQuery:

```
$("#down-year").on("click", function() {
    var newVal = parseInt($("#range").val()) - 1;
    $("#range").val(newVal);
    updateLabel(newVal);
});

$("#up-year").on("click", function() {
    var newVal = parseInt($("#range").val()) + 1;
    $("#range").val(newVal);
    updateLabel(newVal);
});

function updateLabel(num){
    $("#year").html(num);
}
```

Just make sure you parseInt on the value otherwise it will read a string and you'll concatenate a 1 on the end of the value (e.g. range at 2001 when you click, $("#range").val() + 1 will equal 20011, which will shoot your slider to the max value of 2015).